# 日本語に違和感: 「ツアー」ページが全体的に直訳調

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語, ツアー

URL: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour  
原文: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

たとえば冒頭を引用すると

> スタック・オーバーフロー は、プログラマーとプログラミングに熱心の人 の質問と回答のサイトです。Stack Exchange Q&A ネットワーク サイトの一部としてあなたが作成し、運営します。あなたの力を借り、スタック・オーバーフロー に関するすべての質問に対する詳細な回答のライブラリを構築しようと皆で頑張っています。
>
> このサイトはその他のサイトと少し異なります。以下が異なる点です:

今の文章はちょっとあまり魅力的ではありません。下にあるユニコーンに関する質問例も、日本文化の文脈ではあまりぐっときません。

Comment: 量が多いので指摘を先延ばしにしていましたが...ひとまず原文をコピペだけでもしてみることにします。

Comment: ツアーの日本語は私も気になる点が多いです。どう指摘したらいいでしょうか？

Comment: @kawty 下に回答として現状の日本語版を追加してあるので、気になるところを編集して改善するか、コメントしていただけるとよいと思います。古い順に回答を並べかえるとツアーページと同じ順になります。満足いく文章になったらjmacさんに言って反映してもらいましょう。

Comment: Transifex上で見つからなかった「いい質問・避けるべき質問」の箇条書き以外、Transifexに反映しました https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40286111?comment=%2Fq%2F100%2F

Comment: @unarist 「いい質問・避けるべき質問」の箇条書きは、モデレーター権限で編集できるようになっていたので反映しました。

Comment: 現在、直訳調の文体は大きく改善され、読み易くなっていると思います。ありがとうございました。今後、原文の変更への追随などの問題は続くと思いますが、この質問は完了とさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

## Stack overflow へようこそ

(ここにある文は [ツアーページの冒頭文はこれでよいですか?](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1388/30) に分離)

このサイトはその他のサイトと少し異なります。以下が異なる点です:

Comment: 訳案「Stack overflow へようこそ」[カタカナ表記の是非](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430/)については新しく質問を立てました。

Comment: サイトが2回出てくるので読みにくいと思います。原文では We が使われていますが、サービス名をそのまま使った方が分かりやすいと思います。
また、「その他の」の指示語「その」は使わなくても自明なため不要だと感じました。
訳案→「Stack overflow は、他のサイトとは少し異なります。以下が異なる点です:」

Answer (score 1):

### 質問と回答だけに専念できる

**回答を得る**ことがこのサイトの全てです。議論のための掲示板ではありません。余計なおしゃべりもありません。

質問そして...

回答のみ

賛成投票 よい回答には賛成票が入り、**最上位に上がります**。
*最良の回答は最初に表示されるため、いつも簡単に見つかります。*

承認 質問者は、1 つの回答に［承認済み］のマークを付けることができます。
*承認された回答が最良の回答であるとは限りません。その回答が質問者の役にたったというだけです。*

Answer (score 1):

### 質問は、実用的に詳細に

自分が経験した**実際の問題**に関する質問に主眼を置いてください。どのようなことを試してみたか、そして具体的に何をしようとしているかを記述してください。

良い質問:

- 具体的なプログラミングの問題
- ソフトウェア・アルゴリズム
- コーディング技法
- ソフトウェア開発ツール

全ての質問がこの形式に収まるとは限りませんが、**主に意見を求める**質問や、回答ではなく**ディスカッションになりやすい**質問は避けてください。

*改善が必要な質問は、誰かが手直しするまで**クローズ**されることがあります。*

次ような質問は避けて下さい:

- 下調べをしていない質問（調べたことも省かずに教えてください！）
- 製品やサービスの推奨や比較
- 一覧、投票、意見やディスカッションを求める質問
- プログラムを書くのに直結しない事柄

Answer (score 1):

### タグを使って興味のある質問を探す

すべての質問にはそのトピックの**タグが付いて**います。質問が複数のトピックに関連していることがあるため、各質問に 5 個までのタグを付けることができます。

**タグをクリック**して、そのタグの付いた質問のリストを表示したり、タグリストを開いて、おもしろそうなトピックを見つけます。

Answer (score 1):

### 他のユーザーの投票によって信用度が上がる

あなたの質問、回答、編集内容に他のユーザーが**賛成投票**すると、信用度が上がります。

信用度が上がると、投票、コメント、さらに他のユーザーによる投稿の編集などの新しい特権のロックが解除されます。

最高レベルでは、特別な**モデレーション ツール**へのアクセス権が与えられます。コミュニティ モデレーターと連携して、サイトの趣旨と有益性を保つことができます。

Answer (score 1):

### 編集やコメントで投稿を改善する

私たちの目標は、どの質問にも**ベストアンサー**を用意することですので、改善できそうな質問や回答が目にとまったら、**編集**してください。

*編集機能を使って、間違いを修正したり、フォーマットを改善したり、投稿の意味をはっきりさせます。*

**コメント**を使って、情報の追加を依頼したり、質問または回答をはっきりさせます。

***あなた自身**の質問や回答にはいつでもコメントできます。信用度 50 点を獲得すると、どのユーザーの投稿にでもコメントできるようになります。*

再確認:ここは全員が共に学ぶ場です。友好的な態度を保ち役に立つよう努めてください!

Answer (score 1):

### ミッションを達成してバッジを集めよう

バッジは、サイトに参加することで獲得できる特別なイベントを表します。バッジには、銅、銀、金の 3 レベルがあります。

実は、**あなたはすでにバッジを獲得しています**:

Answer (score 1):

### 回答できる質問を探すか、質問してみてください

- 新しい質問を見る
- 質問する

サイトについてより詳しい情報をお探しですか? ヘルプセンターを開く

Answer (score 0):

### Stack overflow は Stack Exchange ネットワークの参加サイトです。

Stack Exchange は、128 の Q&A サイトがあるネットワークで、ちょうどこのサイトのような感じです。サイトの完全リストをご覧ください。