# 原文と一致しない日本語：「ツアー」の説明文

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

場所：
　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

原文：

> Don't ask about...
>
> - Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
> - Product or service recommendations or comparisons
> - Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
> - Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

現在の日本語:

> 次の事柄に関する質問はしないでください...
>
> - 次に直接関係しない事柄: スタック・オーバーフロー
> - 主に意見を求める質問
> - 考えられる回答が多すぎる、または回答が度を越して長くなる可能性がある

日本語案：

```
次のような質問はしないでください...
- あなたが答えを見つけるために何も試していない問題（現在までの成果を見せましょう!）
- 製品やサービスに関する推薦や比較
- 何かに関する一覧、調査、意見、論議など
- コンピューター・プログラムを書くことに直接関係しないこと
```

Answer (score 1):

[日本語に違和感: 「ツアー」ページが全体的に直訳調](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/103/8000) の方で出ていた案が[適用されています](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/100/8000#comment804_100)。

> - 下調べをしていない質問（調べたことも省かずに教えてください！）
> - 製品やサービスの推奨や比較
> - 一覧、投票、意見やディスカッションを求める質問
> - プログラムを書くのに直結しない事柄

Answer (score 0):

もちろん英語のStack Overflowではこれはルールですが、最初から日本語版でも製品やサービスの推薦は避けるべきですか？