# ツアーページの冒頭文はこれでよいですか?

Tags: 討議, ツアー

[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)ページの冒頭部分はモデレーター権限で編集できるので、既にあるメタの質問「[日本語に違和感: 「ツアー」ページが全体的に直訳調](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/100/30)」とは別に質問を立てることにしました。当初の内容に手を加え、以下の文面にしてあります:

> **スタック・オーバーフロー** は、職業プログラマーから週末プログラマーまで、プログラミングに情熱をそそぐ人のためのQ&Aサイトです。ユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティの集まりである、[Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) ネットワークの一部として運営されています。目標は、プログラミングに関するあらゆる質問の詳細な回答集をみんなで作り上げること。ぜひあなたの力を貸してください。

改善案などあれば教えてください。

参考: [英語版のツアーページ](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: 「回答集」だとdetailedの意が消えてしまうので、あえて「詳細な～」としても良いのではないでしょうか？英文ツアーでも"detailed question"/"detailed answer"を強調気味かなと捉えています。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。「詳細な～」を付け加えました。