# ツアーにのせる質問は実際のものでなく、説明のための仮想的なものにしませんか？

Tags: 機能の要求, ツアー

サイト初心者がまず読まされるものとして、[ツアー](//ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)があります。
殆どのサイト初心者は、これだけ読んで参加すると思いますので、多少コストをかけてでも整備しておく価値があると思います。

ここで説明のために用意されているQ&Aは、日本語版ではStack Exchange共通のものではなく、カスタマイズされたものです。
このQ&Aは実際のものとしては特に悪いものでは無いと思いますが、ツアーの一部としては下記の問題があります。

- 質問に直接答えている回答が無い:
  確かに、実際のQ&Aでは直接的な回答でなくとも問題を解決することがありますが、例としてはどうかと思います。
  せめてベストアンサーは質問に直接的な回答を与えているものにするべきです。
- ベストアンサーと他の質問の差がわからない:
  例示されている回答が両方とも同じようなものなので、「よい回答にはプラス票」ですとか、「質問者がベストアンサーを選ぶ」、といった説明の例になっていません。
  例えば、ベストアンサーは質問に直接的に答えていて、次点の回答は別の観点や補足的な内容を扱っている、といった構成にするべきです。
- コメントが情報を持たない感想であり、説明と矛盾している:
  私は「これは初めて知りました。おもしろい」というコメントがあってもよいと思いますが、「情報の追加を依頼したり、質問または回答を明確にします」「余計なおしゃべりもありません」といった説明と矛盾し、例になっていません。

例を出す際にはそれを通じて伝えたい内容があるはずですから、それに沿った例を恣意的で強引であっても用意するべきです。

---

現在の例示Q&Aは以下の通りです。
（現在のデザインだとブラウザの設定などにもよると思いますが、それぞれ冒頭の一部のみが表示されます）

質問：

> ちょっと時間がかかるテストを回しながら開発しています。
>
> ```
> $ python tests.py
> ```
>
> テストが走っている間に次のテストを書いたりして時間の埋め合わせをしていますが、テストが終わったら前回変えたところを忘れないうちにすぐにテスト結果を見て対処したいです。
>
> テストを実行するコマンドが終了したらビープ音か何かを鳴らせばいいかと思うのですが、どうすればいいでしょうか。
>
> SSH越しのシェルでも動作するような方法がよいです。
>
> おまけでコマンドの終了コードが 0 かそうでないかによって別の音 (ビープ音の数が違うのでもよい) にできればさらによいです。(補足: ただし、音は終了コードに関わらず常に鳴らしたい)

+4票の回答（ベストアンサー）:

> Macの場合、sayコマンドが使用できます。自分は長いmakeビルドなどが終わったことを知らせるのに、sayコマンドを使っています
>
> ```
> make && say Done
> ```
>
> 日本語の音声もつかえるので、日本語を喋らせても面白いです
>
> ```
> make && say -v Otoya "終わったよ！"
> ```

コメント:

> これは初めて知りました。おもしろい

+3票の回答:

> テストが失敗した場合に音を鳴らすのであれば
>
> ```
> python test.py || echo ^G
> ```
>
> とします。^G は CTRL-V CTRL-G で入力します。

Comment: ユニコーンの例示は https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/100/%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%ab%e9%81%95%e5%92%8c%e6%84%9f-%e3%83%84%e3%82%a2%e3%83%bc-%e3%83%9a%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%8c%e5%85%a8%e4%bd%93%e7%9a%84%e3%81%ab%e7%9b%b4%e8%a8%b3%e8%aa%bf で問題提起された過去がありますね。英語圏でのunicorn人気(？)に比べると、日本語圏で突然"ユニコーン"が登場して？？？となる方のほうが多い気はします… （英語圏ではInternet memeとしてのunicornを前提としている節がありますが、日本語圏だと馴染みが薄すぎるのではと思います）

Comment: ユニコーンが日本でなじみが無いのは確かですね。ユニコーンの例にこだわるのは本意ではないので、対案の一つとして、回答に移しました。

Answer (score 0):

Stack Exchange共通のツアーでは下記の仮想的なQ&Aが使われています。
このMeta質問で指摘した問題はありませんし、翻訳もtransifexでほぼ終っているようなので、個人的にはこのままでもいいのではないかと思っています。

質問:

> 「ユニコーンがヒナギクを食べないようにするには」
>   台所の裏でたむろするユニコーンは大好きなのですが、ヒナギクをかなり大量に食べてしまいます。どうしたらいいでしょうか？

+4票の回答（ベストアンサー）:

> 一番簡単な解決策は、よくある植物油用スプレーを使ってコーンシロップをヒナギクに軽く散布することです。ユニコーンは甘ったるい匂いが大嫌いなので、何があっても近寄らなくなります。この方法であればヒナギクも傷みません。

コメント:

> スイセンでもうまくいくみたいです！

+3票の回答:

> ヒナギクをもっとたくさん植えましょう！ 通説に反して、ユニコーンは実際にはトウモロコシを食べません。どちらにしてもトウモロコシがおいしいのは晩夏の数か月だけです。ヒナギクがないと機嫌が悪くなり、脱水症になってしまいます。

Comment: 本当に思い付きですが、ユニコーンよりは、例えばネコとかの方がいいかも、と思っています。

Comment: 問題提起については同意しますが、これを使うのは反対です。サイトと全く関連がなく意味不明です。オントピックな内容にした方がいいと思います。https://stackoverflow.com/tour  でもこの質問回答は使われていません。

Comment: どうもユニコーンは駄目そうですね。
猫は実在の動物なので、あくまで例にすぎない、という事が伝わりにくく、「動物の質問をしてもよい場所」と誤解される可能性が心配です(考えすぎかも知れませんが)。もう少し考えてみます。

Comment: このような「お遊び」は人を注目させる効果がある一方で「真面目な内容ではない(=よって読む必要が無い)」と捉えられかねません。ユニコーンでもネコでも同じです。